# WPF binding to My.Settings for radiobuttons (using vb.net)

Tags: wpf, binding, checkbox, radio-button

Following the advice at 
[WPF Binding My.Settings collection to Combobox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204779/wpf-binding-my-settings-collection-to-combobox-items)

I was able to get binding working for checkboxes but not for radiobuttons?

After saving MySettings
the checkbox value is either true or false depending on if the checkbox is checked or not (as expected), while the radiobutton always returns true.

Any insights into what I am doing wrong, or is this a bug?

(ps: I have found a work around, but ...)

```
 xmlns:self="clr-namespace:myprog"  






                    <CheckBox     Name="cbStartDocked"     IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static self:MySettings.Default}, Path=StartDocked}" Margin="8,0,20.706,39" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Start doc_ked</CheckBox>
                    <RadioButton  Name="rbDockLeft"        IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static self:MySettings.Default}, Path=DockLeft}"    Margin="25,0,24,24" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Dock _left</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton  Name="rbDockRight"       IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static self:MySettings.Default}, Path=DockRight}"   Margin="25,0,33,2" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Dock _right</RadioButton>
```

Settings are as they should be, correct capitalization, all boolean all user scope with default value of true or false as needed

Answer (score 0):

Here, for the benefit of others, is the work around I applied:

Private Sub rbDockLeft_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles rbDockLeft.Checked

```
    My.Settings.DockLeft = True
    My.Settings.DockRight = False
```

End Sub

Private Sub rbDockLeft_Unchecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles rbDockLeft.Unchecked

```
    My.Settings.DockLeft = False
    My.Settings.DockRight = True
```

End Sub